# How to access collected jQuery FullCalendar event data?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I work on a project that is based on the [draggable events demo concept](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.1/demos/external-dragging.html).
I would like to be able to access the events data that has been collected as you add events to the calendar.

Is there a hook to access all the data that's been collected? 
I'm thinking something like:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar.getEvents();
```

I'd like to have a button call on the page outside of the calendar that gets all the data that has been collected and sends it back to the server as a string of JSON.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
```

[Documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/)

Comment: How would you Filter all those events? I'd like to get all events that are currently displayed in the calendar

Comment: you can pass a filter function. See http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
$("#btnClear").click(function () {
        var events = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents');
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            var start_date = new Date(events[i].start._d);
            var end_date = '';
            if (events[i].end != null) {
                end_date = new Date(events[i].end._d);
            }
            var title = events[i].title;

            var st_day = start_date.getDate();
            var st_monthIndex = start_date.getMonth() + 1;
            var st_year = start_date.getFullYear();

            var en_day ='';
            var en_monthIndex = '';
            var en_year = '';
            if (end_date != '') {
                en_day = end_date.getDate()-1;
                en_monthIndex = end_date.getMonth()+1;
                en_year = end_date.getFullYear();
            }

            console.log('Title-'+title+', start Date-' + st_year + '-' + st_monthIndex + '-' + st_day + ' , End Date-' + en_year + '-' + en_monthIndex + '-' + en_day);
        }
    });
```